# How to Handle Temporary Columns in Tidyverse Functions Without Overwriting Existing Data?

Tags: r, tidyverse, metaprogramming

I develop functions in `R` using `tidyverse`, where I often need to create temporary columns in the data frame for intermediate steps. However, I'm encountering issues where these temporary columns might overwrite columns already present in the user's data if they have the same name. Here's a minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```r
fun <- function(data, col) {
  data |> 
    mutate(col2 = {{ col }} * 2) |> 
    filter(col2 <= 4) |>
    select(-col2)
}

iris |> fun(Petal.Length)
```

This function works fine unless `col2` already exists in data, in which case it gets overwritten and removed, which we don't want. Of course this is a simple example and we could easily put the calculation for `col2` directly into `filter()`, but this is just to show how such problems would occur.

I'm looking for a way to handle these temporary columns without risking overwriting any existing columns in the user's dataset. I've considered using uncommon naming conventions and dynamically generating unique column names, but these approaches either risk still conflicting with user data or reduce code readability.

Is there an established or recommended method in the tidyverse for handling such scenarios? How can I efficiently create and manage temporary columns in a data frame within a function without affecting the original dataset's structure or existing column names?

Comment: There isn’t really a good, established solution. All fixed names will run into the same potential problem. You could *compute* a column name to make it unique, e.g. find the longest `colnames(data)` entry, append `"x"`, and use that. (Of course an arguably better solution would be *not* to create a temporary column name at all, and instead using a local variable; but this is often not as easy/elegant when using ‘dplyr’).

Comment: This question not only applies to  `data.frame`s but also to other objects like environments. In the latter case you sometimes see * unique * names being wrapped between two or three underscores like `___tmp_col___`, but as you say, this still comes with a risk of conflicting column names - however this risk is much lower in this case.

Comment: @TimTeaFan This scenario is special since it’s a legitimate use-case; whereas there is almost never a good reason to create a name in a user-controlled environment (the `*tmp*` object created during assignment is an exception, but even that could probably be solved differently). — Another common, similar scenario is when a function accepts arbitrary argument names and needs to disambiguate predefined named arguments.

Comment: Just don't create col2:  `data |> filter({{col}} * 2 <= 4)`

Comment: @G. Grothendieck `col2` is indeed not necessary in this example, but in more complex functions nesting computations would make it very unclear what is happening.

Comment: OK. Maybe just raise an error if it already exists. `stopifnot(!exists(ensym(col), data))`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there is a canonical way of dealing with temporary variables inside dplyr-based functions.

One way is to write a function that creates a unique column name stem. The function below `create_tmp_col_name` is, admittedly, a bit over-engineered, but in escence it hashes a string called `"tmp_col"` and tries to use this as variable stem. It's pretty unlikely that any dataset contains a variable named `"2e2a0834ed8cd54664b8ba89f9b98ece"`. But in case it does, the function gets called recursively wrapping `"tmp_col"` in underscores, over and over again, until we find a hash value that is not used as variable stem.

We can then use this variable stem by creating as many temporary names as we need using `paste(tmp_col, 1:n)` where `n` is the number of names we need.

In the actual function we can use `!!` and `sym` or `.data[col_nm]` or embracing syntax `"{{tmp_cols[1]}}"` or just strings depending on whether it is a data-masking or tidy-selection function (see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)).

We can delete all temporary variables with `select(!starts_with(tmp_cols))`.

```r
library(dplyr)

# function that creates a unique variable stem that's not present in the current data
create_tmp_col_name <- function(data, name = "tmp_col") {
  
  tmp_col <- rlang::hash(name)
  
  if(!any(tmp_col == colnames(data))) {
    return(tmp_col)
  } 
  
  Recall(data = data,
         name = paste0("_", name, "_"))
  
}

fun <- function(data, col) {
  
  # createa a vector with unique temporary columns names
  tmp_cols <- paste0(create_tmp_col_name(data), 1:3)
  
  data |> 
    # create temporary columns subsetting vector of temporary columns
    mutate(!! tmp_cols[1] := {{ col }} * 2,
           !! tmp_cols[2] := {{ col }} / 4) |>
    # use `!! sym` notation to filter on temp columns
    filter(!! sym(tmp_cols[1]) <= 4,
           !! sym(tmp_cols[2])  > 0.4
           ) |>
    # deletes all temporary columns
    select(!starts_with(tmp_cols))
}

iris |> fun(Petal.Length)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 2          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
#> 3          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
#> 4          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
#> 5          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
```

As already mentioned by the OP this approach is not very readable.
Alternatively could think about this problem in a more base R way:

First create an empty copy of the the original `data.frame` just keeping the number of rows `data_cp`. Then we can add additional columns as we like, since there are no other columns present. Finally, we apply the filter operations to our original data based on the columns stored in our copied version.

In this case, writing more complex functions gets complicated, especially when we have a bunch of temporary variables and want to introduce some persistent variables into our original data (then the name problem arises again). But for pure filter or order operations this is probably the cleaner approach.

```r
fun2 <- function(data, col) {
  
  # create a copy of your data.frame with 0 columns
  data_cp <- data[, NULL]
  
  # create new colums, names don't matter
  data_cp$col1 <- data[[col]] * 2
  data_cp$col2 <- data[[col]] / 4
  
  # do more data operations on `data_cp` here
  
  # apply changes to your orinial data
  data[which(data_cp$col1 <= 4 & data_cp$col2 > 0.4), ]
}

iris |>
  fun2("Petal.Length")

#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
#> 21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
#> 24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
#> 25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
#> 45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @KonradRudolph good point, I thought it'd be safer, because we delete all variables starting with the string in `tmp_cols` later, but that doesn't matter in this case, so `==` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I like that thought you put into making sure the names are indeed unique. Of course, this uniqueness would then come at the cost of readability. If `fun()` would throw an error, it wouldn't be easy to figure out which temporary column it is referring to. This would be easy to fix (e.g. prefixing a readable name) but I don't see myself deploying this on a large scale yet.

Comment: @koenniem: I came up with another base R approach, which might also be of help.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a function implementing the suggestion from my comment:

```r
unique_colname = function (data) {
  longest = max(nchar(colnames(data)))
  as.name(paste0("tmp_", stringr::str_pad("", longest, pad = "x")))
}
```

Unlike the original suggestion in my comment, this doesn’t merely reuse the longest column name. Instead, it creates a new name of the format `tmp_xxx…`. This has the advantage of providing a more readable message in the case of an error: compare “invalid length in tmp_xxxx” with “invalid length in tmp_disp”. The latter implies that the error is related to the column `disp`, but this isn’t true; `disp` just happens to be the longest column name.

Either way, usage is similar to that in Tim’s answer, i.e.:

```r
fun <- function(data, col) {
  tmp_col <- unique_colname(data)
  data |>
    mutate(!! tmp_col := {{ col }} * 2) |>
    filter(!! tmp_col <= 4) |>
    select(- !! tmp_col)
}
```

(Unlike Tim, I opted to make the function return a *name*, not a character string, to avoid having to repeatedly call `sym()`/`as.name()`; on the flip side, this does not allow easily creating multiple temporary column names. If this is a common requirement, I would generalise the function to the signature `unique_colnames(data, n)`.)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I like that your function returns a name instead of a string, as I feel this is more of a "tidyverse-like" way of thinking. Similar to Tim's solution, I don't feel that masking column names is the way to go. It would be fine for specific situations, but not for every temporary variable creating in your package.